# Django: Get all objects from a specific user

Tags: python, django, listview, django-queryset, django-related-manager

I have a problem when trying to display all the *Announce* objects from a user.
My problem is : Consider that I am logged in as a user with an id=1. When I go to */users/1/* it displays all my posts. But the problem is when I want to display all the posts from another user with id=2 by going to /users/2/, it still display all my Announce objects, and not the user with the id=2.

**models.py**

```
class Announce(models.Model):
    owner        = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='announces')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body         = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
```

**views.py**

```
class UserAnnouncesList(ListView):
    model = Announce
    template_name = 'myApp/user_announces_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_announces_by_user'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Announce.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserAnnouncesList.as_view(), name='user_announces_list'),]
```

**user_announces_list.html**

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% for announce in all_announces_by_user %}
<h1>{{announce.user.username}}</h1>
    <p>{{announce.body}}</p>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Do I have to use some kind of like : Announce.objects.get(pk=???) ?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **`request.user` is the user that is logged in**. You need to **use the `pk`** that is passed as url. This is stored in the `kwargs` dictionary of the listview:

```
class UserAnnouncesList(ListView):
    model = Announce
    template_name = 'myApp/user_announces_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_announces_by_user'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Announce.objects.filter(owner=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: crystal clear ! works perfectly ! thank you very much !